# Removing white from colored vector image on illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a colored image from photoshop where the background is transparent well as some other spots. After using image scan and expand, the transparent background was gone so I reselected the design I made and copied it to another layer. The white background is gone, however, I see that there are still white spots in the design that wasn't transparent.

[image]

I selected them and deleted them, but, it gives me black instead of transparent.

[image]

I'm out of ideas as to how to make these white spots transparent. The same thing with my signature- although I can erase it completely, if I just erase the white parts, I get black.

Comment: What you want to make transparent?
Do you want to remove Gray background-color from that picture?

Comment: You see that white part above the bucket? When I delete it, I get black underneath. Also I get black when I delete the white parts in my letters.